# Where are my dynamically added buttons(VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have come across an issue that has completely bamboozled me.

I have a dynamically added DataGridView with many columns and rows and what I am trying to achieve is on mouse_up I want a button to be drawn over the selected cells. So for example if I select the first 3 cells of row3, a button should be drawn over the 3 cells.

I have tried using the X and Y of each selected cell and convert it to a buttoncolumn but that didn't work. What I currently have is sample code that just adds button to the screen  but they do not appear on the screen (thus the title). Once I get the buttons to appear on the screen I will then try to draw them over the selected cells but I need to get over this hurdle first

This is the code I am using:

```
    'I dynamically add the DataGridView
    Grid = New DataGridView
    Grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Grid.BackgroundColor = Color.White
    Grid.RowHeadersVisible = False
    Grid.AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
    Grid.AllowUserToResizeRows = False

    ...

    TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Grid)

    AddHandler Grid.CellMouseUp, AddressOf Grid_MouseUp

    ...
   'On mouse up it calls the sub to add buttons
    Private Sub Grid_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As         System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 30
        NewButton(i) 'calls the dub
    Next i

End Sub
```

'this is the sub

```
Private Sub NewButton(ByVal ButtonNumber As Integer)

    Dim oButton As Button
    oButton = New Button
    oButton.Enabled = True
    oButton.Location = New Point(ButtonNumber + 50, ButtonNumber + 50)
    oButton.Name = "MyButton" & ButtonNumber.ToString
    oButton.Size = New Size(75, 23)
    oButton.Text = "Button" & ButtonNumber.ToString
    oButton.Visible = True

    oButton.Tag = ButtonNumber

    TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(oButton)
End Sub
```

I would appreciate it if you guys could suggest what I need to change in order to achieve this functionality.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you button is Under the other controls, try calling `oButton.BringToFront()` after you add the button to the Tabcontrol controls.

Comment: you are the man! Thank you so much. They finally appear on the screen. Could I also ask about the next stage? I want to draw the button over the selected cells. Something like for each selected cell, draw a button over it. If there are 3 selected cells its should draw a button over the 3 cells(on same row). Any ideas?

Comment: @Oopsie Daisie: Mark this as solved and create a new question.